# Multiple Merge with Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

What I am trying to accomplish in one shot is update else insert data into 2 tables matching a primary key on one table, and the secondaryID on another.  The collection of the initial data will have multiple rows that have the same secondaryID.  I want most of the latest data.  If it can be added to allow me to do functions on update at the same time, that would be awesome.

```
USE [TestDB]
GO

--DELETING CREATED FUNCTIONS, TABLES, AND TYPES
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.procedures WHERE name = 'sp_Proc_1' AND [TYPE] IN (N'P',N'PC'))
  BEGIN
      DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Proc_1;
  END

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.types WHERE is_user_defined = 1 AND is_table_type = 1 AND name = 'My_Table_Type_1')
    BEGIN
        DROP TYPE dbo.My_Table_Type_1;
    END

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table_Data'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table_Data;
END

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table_1'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table_1;
END

IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table_2'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE Table_2;
END

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Table_1]    Script Date: 6/28/2015 6:15:00 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
--CREATE SAMPLE TABLE WITH DATA
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_Data](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [secondaryID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col3] [int] NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_Data] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO Table_Data (secondaryID,col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('1234','Mickey','Magic Kingdom',1);
INSERT INTO Table_Data (secondaryID,col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('1234','Goofy','Epcot',1);
INSERT INTO Table_Data (secondaryID,col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('1234','Minnie','Disney',2);
INSERT INTO Table_Data (secondaryID,col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('5678','Toy Story','Universal Studios',4);
INSERT INTO Table_Data (secondaryID,col1,col2,col3) VALUES ('5678','Willie','Sea World',5);

--FIRST TABLE FOR DATA TO BE COPIED INTO BY ID
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Table_1(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [secondaryID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col3] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--SECOND TABLE THAT HAS SECONDARY ID AS "UNIQUE ID"
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Table_2(
    [secondaryID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col3] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

--CREATE TABLE TYPE (FOR APPLICATION)
CREATE TYPE dbo.My_Table_Type_1 AS TABLE(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [secondaryID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col1] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col2] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [col3] [int] NULL
)
GO

--CREATE STORED PROCEDURE FOR MULTI MERGE AND MULTI ROW (UPDATE ELSE INSERT)
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Proc_1
@myTBL dbo.My_Table_Type_1 READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @myTBL2 dbo.My_Table_Type_1;
    INSERT INTO @myTBL2
    SELECT * FROM @myTBL;

    MERGE dbo.Table_1 AS Target
    USING @myTBL AS Source
    ON Target.ID = Source.ID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET 
        Target.secondaryID = Source.secondaryID,
        Target.col1 = Source.col1,
        Target.col2 = Source.col2,
        Target.col3 = Source.col3
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT
        (id,secondaryID,col1,col2,col3) 
        VALUES
        (Source.id,Source.secondaryID,Source.col1,Source.col2,Source.col3);  

    MERGE dbo.Table_2 AS Target
    --gets latest data
    USING(SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, SUM(col3) OVER(PARTITION BY secondaryID) sumcol3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY secondaryID ORDER BY id DESC) rn FROM @myTBL)t WHERE rn = 1) AS Source
    --USING @myTBL AS Source
    ON Target.secondaryID = Source.secondaryID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET
        Target.col1 = Source.col1,
        Target.col2 = Source.col2,
        --Target.col3 = Target.col3 + Source.col3
        Target.col3 = sumcol3
        --Target.col3 = 7 --<---------------THIS DOES NOT GET SAVED
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT
        (secondaryID,col1,col2,col3)
        VALUES
        (Source.secondaryID,Source.col1,Source.col2,Source.col3);
END
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

--GET DATA AND EXECUTE PROC (SIMULATE APPLICATION)
DECLARE @tbl My_Table_Type_1

INSERT INTO @tbl
SELECT * FROM Table_Data;

EXECUTE sp_Proc_1 @myTBL = @tbl

--FIRST SELECT IS CORRECT, should list every value
SELECT * FROM Table_1;

--SECOND SELECT IS ***NOT*** CORRECT
SELECT * FROM Table_2;
--I WANT THIS DATA TO SHOW 2 ITEMS
--  1234    Minnie  Disney      4
--  5678    Willie  Sea World   9
```

Comment: You can use ORDER BY in the source. Use the `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT FROM Table_1 ORDER BY`

Comment: I don't follow.  At what select?

Comment: @user2829970: which field (if any) shows you that it is the last one in the batch associated with secondaryId? Is there something that should be ordered by in order to determine which row is the most recent?

Comment: Yes.  Just edited.  ORDER BY id ASC when Selecting Sample table data

Comment: Ok.... so there has to be something wrong with the code.   Under Table_2 Merge, I put Target.col3 = 7, and it still saved the 5 from Table_data Row 5 and 3.... Why is merge completely ignoring my manual input??

Answer (score 2):

I think you can accomplish this with `window` function in `using` part of `merge` statement:

```
MERGE dbo.Table_2 AS Target
USING(SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, 
                            SUM(col3) OVER(PARTITION BY secondaryID) sumcol3,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY secondaryID ORDER BY id DESC) rn
                      FROM @myTBL)t WHERE rn = 1) AS Source
....
UPDATE SET
    Target.col1 = Source.col1,
    Target.col2 = Source.col2,
    Target.col3 = Source.sumcol3
...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
    (secondaryID,col1,col2,col3)
    VALUES
    (Source.secondaryID, Source.col1, Source.col2, Source.sumcol3);
```

Comment: That works to get the correct latest line (highest id per secondaryID).  Any way to be able to get the col3 to add while going through also?  Keeping performance at heart.

Comment: @user2828970, your question was unclear for me. Can you elaborate?

Comment: That same merge statement for Table_2, col3 should be added (mathematically) Target.col3 = Target.col3 + Source.col3.  Tried different ways but does not add them.

Comment: The last lines of the code section on the post has the output i'm attempting to accomplish

Comment: did not work, unfortunately its not sum'ing them.  I tried to copy them into a table variable just prior to the table_2 merge and then do a select sum for Target = SELECT SUM(col3) as col3 from seperateCopiedTBL. but that fails also.  almost as if the other rows don't exist when using merge.  Don't have to use "merge" function but thought it would be cleaner at least if it didn't "protect" against multiple rows with same matching criteria.  It doesn't iterate.

Comment: it should work: check the query `SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, 
                            SUM(col3) OVER(PARTITION BY secondaryID) sumcol3,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY secondaryID ORDER BY id DESC) rn
                      FROM @myTBL)t WHERE rn = 1`   What does it return?

Comment: I did a copy and paste.  it returns 1)1234,Minnie,Disney,2    AND    2)5678,Willie,Sea World,5... which have the highest id per secondaryID

Comment: @user2828970, it can not return that. Where is sumcol3?

Comment: i copied the entire script back in the post.  with the first part of your help, I get the rows that I was looking for.  But even if I put anything manually for the columns under the Table_2 Merge UPDATE... , it does not get saved.  Its ignoring what I'm putting at just saving whats in the "Source"

Comment: @user2828970, man your tabe_2 is empty, what do you want to update? add insert part in second merge

Comment: @user2828970, see edits, you should change your insert part as well to insert sumcol3 instead of col3

Comment: sumcol3 needed to go to the insert portion of the merge, not update

Comment: @user2828970, I can't tell. You should check execution plans and add some index if needed on `secondaryID` column.